Error added @nuxt/ui to nuxt project: Pre-transform Error
My nuxt project is working fine. When adding  Module @nuxt/ui with npx nuxi@latest module add ui, I get an error:
Pre-transform error: Failed to resolve import "#tailwind-config/theme/colors" from "node_modules/.pnpm/@nuxt+ui@2.16.0_focus-trap@7.5.4_nuxt@3.11.2_@opentelemetry+api@1.8.0_@parcel+watcher@2.4.1_@_sixng7mtxzjwvb5hrwzhbdkxzi/node_modules/@nuxt/ui/dist/runtime/plugins/colors.mjs?v=bcf8a7ff". Does the file exist?

My nuxt.config.ts is as follows:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@pinia/nuxt", "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxt/ui"],
  css: ['~/assets/css/main.css'],
  devServer:{
    host: 'localhost',
  }
})

My package.json is as follows:
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/ui": "^2.16.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "highlight.js": "^11.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "marked": "^12.0.2",
    "marked-highlight": "^2.1.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.7",
    "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "packageManager": "pnpm@9.1.1+sha512.14e915759c11f77eac07faba4d019c193ec8637229e62ec99eefb7cf3c3b75c64447882b7c485142451ee3a6b408059cdfb7b7fa0341b975f12d0f7629c71195",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "^1.3.1",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.12.0"
  }
}

I want to be able to use @nuxt/ui module normally

Give a try to those 2 issues: https://github.com/nuxt/ui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Pre-transform+Error

Had the same problem, fixed by switching the order of modules from ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxt/ui"] -> to ["@nuxt/ui" , "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss" ]

This is the fix for me. I had installed Tailwind before adding Nuxt/UI and the modules were in the order that they were installed. Thanks for the help!
